# Tor won't start by itself

Tags: 20.04, shortcuts, tor

I've been using Tor Browser for a while and it's always worked fine, but now when I click on the Tor icon nothing happens.
The solution I've found for now is running this from the Tor Browser directory:
`./start-tor-browser.desktop`
but I have to do this every time. Any idea how to solve this?

Update: I've managed to create a desktop shortcut by copying the "start-tor-browser.desktop" file onto the desktop -> right click -> "Allow Launching". The shortcut does appear there when Tor is running, but when I add it to Favorites and then close Tor this shortcut won't launch it.
I'd still like to find a way to get the shortcut in the sidebar to work.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut might have been unlinked or broken. If you know where that command links to, i.e the directory or application, try creating another shortcut or relinking the shortcut to the correct app/directory.